# find friends who also tweet this

Tags: php, smarty

I'm working out a social tool like twitter, but I got stuck on "who also tweet this twitter."

There's a list of twitters on my page, and I wanna display who also tweeted this for each tweet.

I'm using MySQL + php + Smarty.

Here's the code:
/* ---- php ---- */

```
// Get twitters that tweeted over 200 times.
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, content, user, tweets FROM twitter_list WHERE tweets > '200'");
$twitter_array = array();
while($tweet_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    array_push($twitter_array, $tweet_row);
    // Get the users who tweeted these twitters.
    $twitter_id = $tweet_row['id'];
    // Find out 5 friends who also tweeted this twitter. twitter_relation stores who tweets what.
    $friends_who_also_tweet = mysql_query("SELECT tid, twitter_id, user_id FROM tweet_relation WHERE twitter_id = '$twitter_id' ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 5");
    $friends_who_also_tweet_array = array();
    while($friends_who_also_tweet_row = mysql_fetch_array($friends_also_tweet_array)){
        array_push($friends_who_also_tweet_array, $friends_who_also_tweet_row);
    }
    if($friends_who_also_tweet_array){
        $sm->assign("fwat", $friends_who_also_tweet_array);
    }
}
if($twitter_array){
    $sm->assign("twitter", $twitter_array);
}
$smarty->display('twt.html');
```

/* ---- HTML: twt.html ---- */

```
...
{section name=twitter loop=$twitter}
<div class="content">{$twitter[twitter].content}</div>
<div class="who_also_tweet">
  {section name=who loop=$fwat}
  <div class="i_also_tweet">{$fwat[who].user_id}</div>
  {/section}
</div>
{/section}
```

I wish to get the array of twitter, and for each twitter, retrieve the 5 users who tweets it. But it only display the first twitter's users, I suspect while() might be wrong but cannot find it out. Anyone could lend me a hand? Many thanks.

Comment: Take a sec to reformat that code and you'll probably get more help.

Comment: @ChrisMoll You mean the thought is correct, right?

Comment: Well, I don't really understand the goals entirely.  Are you creating your own "twitter", or using the real thing?  The real Twitter has an API for this kind of thing, but you're pulling everything from your own database.

Comment: @ChrisMoll It's a twitter-like thing built by my own. I thought metaphor would be a faster way to understand what I'm doing...

Answer (score 1):

```
$twitter_array = array();
```

then:

```
if($twitter_array){
    $sm->assign("twitter", $twitter_array);
}
```

You never added anything to that array.  I'm assuming you mean to do it here (since `$tweet_array` is never declared):

```
array_push($tweet_array, $tweet_row);
```

In fact, this variable also gets assigned and then never referred to as well:

```
$friends_who_also_tweet
```

Your variable naming is really confusing, and I think it may be contributing to your problems.

Edit: Also, why do you assign this with every iteration of the first While loop?  It is just going to overwrite the previous values:

```
if($friends_who_also_tweet_array){
        $sm->assign("fwat", $friends_who_also_tweet_array);
    }
```

Comment: Thx for ur patient and ur reply. I think $tweet_array should be $twitter_array, which I've edited. I'll take your suggestion and go further test.